# MOSFET drain current

Tags: mosfet

I have recently started studying MOSFETs.  Looking at the classic Id-Vds characteristic, it is not clear to me how much current flows in the drain.

I often notice in power MOSFETs current values of 10A, 30A or even higher, but I don't understand how these values are reached/calculated.

If I have, for example, Vgs>Vgs(th) so the MOSFET is on and a resistive load of a few ohms (e.g. even 50 ohms) which requires a 12V supply and I connect it to the drain, I get a maximum of 12V/50=240mA. It seems a MOSFET would be wasted as the current would be limited to this value.

Do I need to use a Vcc of hundreds of volts to reach the tens of amperes indicated on the datasheets?

Let me try to explain myself better:

How do I get, say, 40A on the drain? Even with a very low resistor I would be limited by the Vdc (12V in the example.) Even a few ohms would cause a maximum current under 1A with Vcc=12V.

Comment: In situations where you use these MOSFETs, your load may be much lower resistance than 50 ohms. I've seen motors that have a 12V nominal voltage, beefy wiring, and easily take tens of amps in operation.

Comment: In DC-DC converters for example we often use FETs in the range of 1 milliohm, so it doesn't take much voltage to get 10s of amps.  In AC/DC converters we're often dealing with higher on-resistance FETs, but also higher voltages (say 400 V for a PFC).  The Id vs Vds and Vgs curves basically tell the story.

Comment: @JohnD However, in addition to the rds(on) of the mosfet .. it is my understanding that the load resistance and the power supply also have an influence.

Comment: @KaleM Yes of course. If your supply can't support the current or the resistance of whatever is connected to your FET limits the current draw you can't somehow get "extra" current into your FET.  I was just giving specific examples of where FETs are used and are able to switch significant currents.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get, say, 40A on the drain? Even with a very low resistor I would be limited by the Vdc (12V in the example.) Even a few ohms would cause a maximum current under 1A with Vcc=12V.

You would use a load of less than 'a few ohms', and a MOSFET with an on resistance of much less than 'a few ohms'.

For instance, with a 100 mΩ load, a MOSFET with 10 mΩ R<sub>DS</sub>, and negligible wiring and battery internal resistance, you would get 12 / 0.11 = 109 A flowing. Increase the load resistance to get down to 40 A.

Comment: So my reasoning is correct ... and usually you use loads of a few mΩ so you have a lot of current (if needed). There are no practical examples in the book, and I had immediately thought of connecting on the drain 1k ohms ... and it didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> I often notice in power MOSFETs current values of 10A, 30A or even higher...

I just searched Digi-key and found [690 active FETs](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoGwAwA4qgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iAEwAsC8AzCMQJxVVvPg0wNUDsXKgwRg4AViEixMKaLgRiVBPwYKhLMMtlK2cGopAwECGk2LHTNLpYbmQ-EzB0Ong4o-pIPT68VMS7iAB4t7ULCwwLEEscHDOXPS0LnT8-LRcmnAs9qlpfiAsNOKOXGJwDGJlCgziBWKhdNWNLGUyVcRg7YZ5wm1gdPUD4gNtxWCSnRMMOW2idnNgDEOxMFRlNPpUk9xbLgNbQQcGRwbiIhsjCDvD-JobaaIPjvYDCMutneIS918-618BjAbuczPVxFEaADwBCiq9YTRwVFKmVGAZUXB%2BAlOms7HBUcIUTjEQtOgh2PQyuTlEdqSYqewsVS6vwbtcaEyyaoYLTIogqZEOuAEBEImVNGBseAJTB6mxItCwPLZeKSndVSxruK1mAjpr9J9pTl%2BAUqEsqFKzXweUIJnpbfxddCzdcLkowOz8e7ouJDWbovAhGaBIZ2AI6kGrqHth7nRa1i5hDzzlJk4mGMmgknVKaZnahJsPYmDISC1plgWqPF7LRKpEC%2BkSg3tonxKFQkI29c-V2U0pfashDAGs7cY6h8J0hOGCbp8Yh8sMwuzDsLTQiqv0iwO8RikUVUot4HDxw1jZYqFQ6ycqb8hahHewgITRwHybJQ-TCLP%2BuvdQ7pihq8GsEIPj6zoIPoQraOwfpJHwQgmKEEE5H0SgiiKiaxHcNaaM4ppsMoBHLGaGh4X%2BagVB%2BxBqOwUJcLRCogAAusQAAOAAuUAgAAyhxABOACWAB2ADmIAAL6dJqrTQCAaCQFgeBEKQFAgPizFSSAAC06xyQpAkAK4qWQkCUDsrSaVpemUOg%2BBcZpQA) with maximum drain current < 1 A.

This [NTR4003N](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ntr4003n-d.pdf) would be appropriate for your \$50\Omega, 12V\$ application.

[image]

> Do I need to use a Vcc of hundreds of volts to reach the tens of amperes indicated on the datasheets?

The data sheet of a FET may be capable of 40 A, but the internal resistance from drain to source \$R_{DSon}\$ may be the specification of interest. An \$R_{DSon}\$ of\$1\Omega\$ would dissipate 1W of power. This may require a heatsink. To acheive a max current of 40A, the \$R_{DSon}\$ must be very low.

> How do I get, say, 40A on the drain?

The resistor from drain to Vdd would be \$300m\Omega\$ for 12V to provide 40A. But the resistance \$R_{DSon}\$ needs to be much lower.

For example, the FET [MCAC50N03](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/MCAC50N03(DFN5060).pdf) has an \$R_{DSon}<5m\Omega\$ to acheive that, Even so significant heatsinking is required. Actually the sum of the drain resistance and \$R_{DSon}\$ must be \$300m\Omega\$,

[image]

[image]

A better choice might be the [SUM40014M](https://www.vishay.com/docs/77646/sum40014m.pdf) It has an \$R_{DSon}<1m\Omega\$. This comes with a maximum drain current of 299A. At 40A the heatsinking requirements are reduced.

> or example, Vgs>Vgs(th) so the MOSFET is on

\$V_{GS}\$ must be much greater than \$V_{GSth}\$ to acheive \$I_D=40A\$. Read the data sheets very carefully.

> It seems a MOSFET would be wasted

The choice of MOSFET depends on other parameters as well. Power dissipataion is often overlooked by thos starting out. The application should make the choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you are absolutely correct. Maximum drain current is constrained by the load, and the supply voltage.

If you want more drain current, either increase the voltage available to the load, or decrease the resistance of the load, that's all you can do, and it really is as simple as that.

However, you seem to think that "a few ohms" is a small resistance, which isn't really true. For instance, if the load is a 12V motor, it may have winding resistance of 0.5Ω, which would draw \$\frac{12V}{0.5\Omega}=24A\$, if the transistor's own channel resistance \$R_{DS}\$ is small in comparison to 0.5Ω

Low resistance loads like this (sub-ohm) are commonplace, which is why there exists an abundance of MOSFETs with channel resistance \$R_{DS}\$ in the milliohms (or less).

Conversely, there are many applications in which the load is many ohms or even kilohms. It would be silly to use a big chunky MOSFET capable of passing hundreds of amps, for a load that requires only milliamps. For those applications there exist signal MOSFETs, like the famous 2N7000, which are smaller and cheaper, but which have much more significant \$R_{DS(ON)}\$.